# Getting a black screen after instating Pantheon

Tags: desktop-environments

I just now installed pantheon desktop environment and it's only showing a black screen. What do I do now? How do I go back to unity? After I logged out and chose unity I still get a black screen. Please help!

Comment: Тоже был черный экран. Прогрузился через секунд 40-60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you have to restart for the desktop manager to truly switch -- just make sure "Ubuntu" is selected when the machine turns back on.

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
unity --reset
```

Comment: How do I restart desktop manager? And how do I open terminal when I get black screen?